# Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.3 64bit Freezes on boot

Tags: boot, gnome, system-installation

[image: ims]  - this screen, but without the memory test.

My laptop had Windows 8/8.1 on it - can't remember now. I initially wanted Ubuntu as an OS, so I downloaded the .iso, created a bootable usb and installed it. It froze every time I tried to start the computer.

Left it for two weeks, did some thinking, I want Ubuntu Gnome now. Download the iso - md5sum check it; good to go. Install with bootable USB- same issue. Now it'll either freeze with a slightly lit up black screen, or it'll load into the attached picture, and freeze after selecting an option.

I've reinstalled a few times, completely rewriting the harddrive each time (thinking that might clear away whatever was corrupted). But now I'm just frustrated and at a dead end.

To be clear, I'm not trying to dual boot, I just want a working Ubuntu Gnome OS on my laptop.

"ubuntu-gnome-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso" is the filename

Answer (score 0):

DDR2 memory clock fixed at **200MHz** in motherboard firmware **BiOS** **CMOS** **setting** solved my *Random Screen Garble Freeze* bug related to NViDiA graphics driver, without any graphics driver update :)

DDR2 memory clock = "**Auto**" = old default :-(
 DDR2 memory clock = "**200MHz**" = new fix :-)

motherboard = ASUS = M2N MX SE PLUS;
BiOS = version 602 AMi BiOS from ASUS;
NViDiA graphics chip = GeForce6150SE;
DDR2 = 4GB( 2GB+2GB ) Transcend

"Auto" setting in BiOS CMOS was defaulting to 400MHz DDR2 memory clock which used to randomly freeze & garble my display screen;

i gave up NViDiA driver update as it had many other issues like ***missing 1366x768*** pixel option;

i used Ubuntu built-in xrandr & cvt for 1366x768 pixel screen setup, instead of using NViDiA graphics driver update ( just added the below 2 lines at the beginning of ***/etc/gdm/Init/Default*** text file:;

```
xrandr --newmode 1366 85.25 1368 1440 1576 1784 768 771 781 798

xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1366
```

i don't need NViDiA graphics driver update anymore